# Glide not loading image into ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-glide

I have an ImageView nested inside a linear layout:

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tile_background"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/coverTile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/image_frame_community"
            android:imageUrl="@{sponsorship.coverTileUri}">

        </ImageView>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postActionText"
                style="@style/ActionFont"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                tools:text="@string/watch_respond">

            </TextView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_36dp">

            </ImageView>


        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

I also have an extension function for the ImageView that uses Glide and is bound to the layout with databinding:

```
    fun ImageView.loadImage(uri: String, progressDrawable: CircularProgressDrawable) {

    val options = RequestOptions().placeholder(progressDrawable).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)

    this.clipToOutline = true

    Glide.with(context)
        .setDefaultRequestOptions(options)
        .load(uri).into(this)


}

@BindingAdapter("android:imageUrl")
fun loadImage(view: ImageView, url: String) {
    view.loadImage(url, getProgressDrawable(view.context))
}




fun getProgressDrawable(context: Context): CircularProgressDrawable {
    return CircularProgressDrawable(context).apply {
        strokeWidth = 10f
        centerRadius = 50f
        start()
    }
```

In my RecyclerView logs I can see that every model loaded into it has the URI that is being passed into glide, but neither the image nor the progress drawable is appearing in about half of the Views. The parents are just collapsing and shrinking each ViewHolder. What is wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

for the binding adapter to work you must work on static function, in kotlin case it would be a companion object and add @JvmStatic, like this:

```
companion object{
@BindingAdapter("android:imageUrl")
@JvmStatic
    fun loadImages(view: ImageView, url: String){
        view.loadImage(url, getProgressDrawable(view.context))
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using this method to extend ImageView class. I don't think I can give it a companion object. Should I just make a separate class for this method?